# Get number of days between 2 dates of this format in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, datediff

I have 2 dates value in Excel. They are `20170124;202000` (24Jan2017 2020hrs 00secs) and `20170515;021146` (15May2017 0211hrs 46secs). I want to get the number of days between these 2 dates.

I tried to use the formula `=DATEDIF(G838,G839,"md")` where the first 2 parameters are cells containing the dates. The value returned was `#VALUE!`.

What Excel formula or VBA function can I use to get the number of days between the 2 dates?

Comment: normally Excel shows this value, when the column has not enough width to show full value it actually contains.

Comment: @ Nirav Madariya, I confirm it is not due to lack of width.

Comment: DateDif function accepts the dates as arguments and the error returned simply means the cell G838 and G839 are not dates or dates as Text.

Comment: @NiravMadariya the insufficient column width shows #### in the cell not #Value!. :)

Comment: @sktneer, I have converted the cells to date format but DATEDIF still does not work. You can try the same on Excel. I believe you will get the same result.

Comment: In a blank cell type the formula =ISNUMBER(G838). What do you get True or False. If you get False that means those are not dates. Excel treats dates as numbers.

Comment: @sktneer, Thanks for the tip. I got FALSE. But how to proceed? I do not wish to change the contents of the cell. Can I solve the problem without changing the contents?

Comment: @user781486 01/01/2017 is diplayed as 20170101 or 2017011? are the data values always 8 characters long?

Comment: Select G838 and use Text to column on Data tab --> Delimited --> Finish. Does that change it to a real date and see if Isnumber returns true this time. Repeat this for all the date cells or columns.

Comment: @Gowtham Shiva, they are always 8 characters long.

Comment: @sktneer, isnumber() returns false despite using Text to column.

Comment: What is the actual cell content of G838 and G839?

Comment: sktneer, it is `20170124;202000`

Comment: I added a solution. See if that produces the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.......

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(LEFT(G838,4),MID(G838,5,2),MID(G838,7,2)),DATE(LEFT(G839,4),MID(G839,5,2),MID(G839,7,2)),"d")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, the answer returned is 21. There are surely more than 21 days between `20170124;202000` and `20170515;021146`.

Comment: I discovered how to get the correct answer. A little modification to your answer. Instead of using "md", using "d". I have edited your answer. Thanks a lot. You're brilliant!

Comment: You're welcome! I used "md" because it was in your original formula and thought that is what you want to use an argument so didn't change that. :) Anyways glad that your issue has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the string in cell `A1`, use the formula to convert it to an actual date before finding the difference,

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))
```

You can include this directly in your formula too.